# loop into loop with dynamic field name

Tags: abap

THE PROBLEM: I have 2 tables like this:

TABLE 1: HR table with many columns and rows

TABLE 2 :
table with list of columns that i need to read from table 1

[image: MY TABLES IMAGE]

In table 1 I need to loop all row and I need to check all the fields from table 2, if it has "X" in the field, i need print the field description from table 2.

I try do it with nested loop (loop table 1, and each loop iteration loop table 2 and check all the fields of the row) and I can't use variable on table- (i need variable for the loop in  ).

MY CODE:

```
LOOP AT lt_hrp9229  INTO ls_hrp9229 
  LOOP AT lt_otype_fields INTO ls_otype_fields .
   IF ls_hrp9229-ls_otype_fields-FIELD_NAME = 'X'.
    ev_descript_data = ev_descript_data && ','  &&  ls_otype_fields-Field_description.
   ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

I have problem in this row:

```
IF ls_hrp9229-ls_otype_fields-FIELD_NAME = 'X'
```

i can't use dynamic field name from the loop.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using FIeld-Symbol.

```
 LOOP AT lt_hrp9229 INTO ls_hrp9229.
      lv_index = sy-tabix.
      LOOP AT lt_s_fields INTO ls_s_fields.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT ls_s_fields-field_name OF STRUCTURE ls_hrp9229
        TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_s_fields_value>).

        IF <ls_s_fields_value> = 'X'.
          ev_descript_data = ev_descript_data && ' , '  && ls_s_fields-field_desc  .
        ENDIF.
      ENDLOOP.
      ls_et_hrp9229-descript_data = ev_descript_data.
      MODIFY et_hrp9229 INDEX lv_index FROM ls_et_hrp9229 TRANSPORTING descript_data .
      CLEAR ev_descript_data.
    ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <l_flag> TYPE FLAG.

ASSIGN COMPONENT ls_otype_fields-field_name OF STRUCTURE ls_hrp9229 TO <l_flag>.
IF SY-SUBRC = 0 AND <l_flag> = abap_true.
  ...
ENDIF.
```

Comment: This seems correct, but this answer would be even better if it would point out what happens here and why it solves the problem.

Comment: The detailed description of ASSIGN COMPONENT can be found in the ABAP documentation, I just wanted to give a hint to find the relevant keywords.

Comment: If you will use this approach on more than one part of your code, I recommend creating a helper method or Form, to get the value of a dynamic structure.  This will make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
DATA: lt_hrp9229 TYPE TABLE OF HRP9229.
DATA: ev_descript_data TYPE string.

SELECT *
  FROM dd03l
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_otype_fields)
  WHERE tabname = 'HRP9229'.

LOOP AT lt_hrp9229 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_9229>).
  LOOP AT lt_otype_fields ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fields>).
    ASSIGN COMPONENT <fs_fields>-fieldname OF STRUCTURE <fs_9229> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<field_description>).
    CHECK sy-subrc = 0.
   IF <field_description> = 'OBJID'.
    ev_descript_data = ev_descript_data && ','  && <fs_fields>-rollname. " pull your FIELD_DESC here instead 
   ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: The approach t use ASSIGN COMPONENT seems correct here, but I think the line two after that should read `IF <field_description> = 'X'.` Not sure where you got `'OBJID'` from. The answer could further be improved by explaining what ASSIGN COMPONENT actually does and why it solves this problem.

Comment: yep, it's up to the actual business-requirement, I just gave the sample